# Ошибка в фрагменте с jetpack compose

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

У меня есть activity на java в которой я хотел бы использовать один фрагмент на котлине с jetpack compose, а остальные на джаве с обычной xml разметкой. Я добавил в фрагмент `androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView`, написал фрагменты на jetpack compose. При компиляции появляется ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.theona/com.example.theona.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.theona:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #33 in com.example.theona:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment

...

Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.theona.ui.main.ChatsFragment: make sure class name exists
```

Собственно вопрос - можно ли использовать compose фрагменты в activity на java?

Comment: Проверьте, точно ли у вас есть класс `ChatsFragment` с пакетом `com.example.theona.ui.main`?

Comment: Да, конечно, но это kotlin класс. @Vadik